# building snaps for different architectures

Tags: cross-platform, snapcraft, snap

I'm currently working on creating a snap for Apache IoTDB, that should build for both arm64 and amd64 architectures.

Now I know this should be possible, but the problem I'm having is, that if I use "stage-packages" one of the packages is "openjdk-11-jre-headless", when listing the content of the snap in both cases I can only see "squashfs-root/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64"

I'm building a "core22" image and defined this for the architectures:

```
architectures:
 - build-on: [arm64, amd64]
   build-for: [arm64]
 - build-on: [arm64, amd64]
   build-for: [amd64]
```

I should mention I'm building on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM on an M2 Mac.